# Cannot install beta version of app on windows phone 8.1from windows phone store

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, windows-phone-store

I had submitted one of my windows phone 8.1 app on the windows phone store and marked it as beta release.. I had provided the couple of testers microsoft emails as test users(couple of emails separated with semicolon) and submitted the app.. The app was approved and when i try to install on my device using the tester microsoft account, then it shows the error message like "You don't have permissions to install the app".

Below is the screen shot of beta selection of the app and emails provided. Please let me know if i am missing anything like any permissions to be given to testers in beat release of the app.

Thanks
Kalyan

Comment: Maybe this article will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link Barnstokkr. We had followed the same link and we had added test users emails and submitted the app. But we are having the same message when trying to install the app.

Comment: Have the same problem. Used the "promotion code" feature to install beta on Window Phone 10, but will not allow install on Windows Phone 8.1. Having to rewrite using activation codes for WP8.1